# Change color of checkbox field when checked

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I have a check box field with box label colored in green. I need to change the color of the boxlabel (say: yellow) when a user checks the checkbox. i tried validating the checkbox, but it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

```
xtype :  'checkbox',
id: 'checkbox1',
name : 'checkbox',
style: 'background-color : #BCF5A9',
boxLabel: 'Mycheckbox'
//I tried the below handler function. but it doesnt work
handler: function (checkbox, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                style : 'background-color: #ddd';
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to change the color of the boxLabel, try this way.

```js
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  bodyPadding: 10, 
  title: 'Checkbox Test', 
  items: [{
    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
    id: 'checkbox1',
    name: 'checkbox',
    style: {
      color: 'green'
    },
    boxLabel: 'MyCheckbox',
    handler: function(checkbox, checked) {
      if (checked) {
        checkbox.el.setStyle("color","red");
        //checkbox.setBoxLabel('<span style="color:red">MyCheckbox</span>');
      } else {
         checkbox.el.setStyle("color","green");
        //checkbox.setBoxLabel('<span style="color:green">MyCheckbox</span>');
      }
    }
  }],
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css">
```

Comment: nice. but is there a way to do this without html tags?

Comment: Updated in answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to color the whole checkbox? If so here's the snippet:

```html
{
 xtype :  'checkbox',
 id: 'checkbox1',
 name : 'checkbox',
 style: 'background-color : #BCF5A9',
 boxLabel: 'Mycheckbox',
 //I tried the below handler function. but it doesnt work
 handler: function (checkbox, checked) {
  if (checked) {
   checkbox.setStyle('backgroundColor', '#ddd');
  } else {
   checkbox.setStyle('backgroundColor', '#BCF5A9');
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I was trying the same thing but I came to SFO You already posted answer. :) Here is fiddle. Have a look. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1su5